# Django compatibility with BeautifulSoup's lxml parser

Tags: django, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

I create a website using Django 1.11.12 with Python 3.4. Yesterday, I stumbled over something strange.

My function looks something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

def foo():
    t = "bla bla blubb"
    s = Soup(t, 'lxml')
    # do stuff
```

When Django calls the function the first time, everything works and I get a result. However, when running the same function a second time, the website freezes and I get a Gateway Timeout after some time.

When now only changing the parser:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

def foo():
    t = "bla bla blubb"
    s = Soup(t, 'html.parser') # changed from lxml to html.parser
    # do stuff
```

Everything works fine over and over again.

Is this just with my system (perhaps I messed up something)? What may be the reason for this behaviour?

I am glad for any suggestions.

Comment: What input do you put into the soup? Could be some bug in the parser.

Comment: @AndrejKesely The input is a string. This string may have xml tags in it, but not necessarily. But only by using the given example string, the website freezes. :/

Answer (score 0):

I have one in a django site using:

```
contents = urllib.request.urlopen(request.POST['url']).read()
parsed = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html5lib")
title = parsed.find('title').text


title ---> StackOverflow - Where developers...
```

But as far as lxml, I haven't used it that way and couldn't tell you, but maybe html5lib might better?

Comment: This would strengthen my and Andreij Kesely's hypothesis that my issue may be a bug in the lxml parser... Thanks for your opinion!